# AVCaptureSession not feeding data to iPhones below iPhone X

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, iphone-8

If you are working on a project and the iPhone camera is not passing through data (you do get a view), with current setting AVCaptureSession.Preset.Photo .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not a question.

Comment: This seems like potentially valuable content for a question and answer, but please edit your question to rephrase it as a Question and then add a self-Answer to answer it.

Comment: Do not answer your question in the Question part. In the Question part, ask a question. In the Answer part, answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to AVCaptureSession.Preset.high . iPhone X and above are good to go with .Photo, but lower versions will get stuck on this.